# Как найти кнопку и передать в requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Что делать, если у кнопки (В данном случае кнопка Login) нету поля "name="?

Как можно передать ее для data={'submit': ''}?

```
import requests


URL = 'https://instagram.com/'
r = requests.post(URL, data={'username': 'example@mail.ru', 'password': 'mypassword', 'submit': '**what_is**'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По моему вы делаете что-то совсем не то:

**requests.get**. Get-запросы не предназначены для передачи полезной нагрузки серверу (*payload*), для этого существуют POST, PUT, DELETE

**URL**. Очень интересно, как вы вообще узнали, что авторизация происходит именно по этому пути. Я проверил, урл должен быть "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/", а метод POST. Как я это узнал: запускаете фаерфокс или хром, заходите на целевой сайт и открываете отладчик встроенный в браузер, там открывается вкладка Network. Вводите логин, пароль и нажимаете Login. В отладчике, на вкладке Network появиться новая запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если присмотреться к тому, как instagram отправляет данные для авторизации, то мне становиться как-то не оч: обратите внимание на **enc_password**. Совершенно неизвестно что это такое, как это генерируется и зачем это нужно.

**API**. У Instagram есть официальный, документированный [API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/), через него то и нужно реализовывать общение с сервисом. Во всяком случае так меньше вероятность того, что вас забанят как бота, или что вам все время будут подсовывать капчи

**Абстракция над API**. Еще более хороший вариант - поищите готовую библиотеку для работы с Instagram

Comment: Я перепутал get с post запросом (Подправил). Но всё же, возможно ли без API авторизоваться, использовав requests?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Обратите внимание на такую вещь как sessions в requests. С ее помощью вам не нужно будет каждый раз отправлять в ручную все те куки которые сервер вам дает

Comment: Хорошо, попробую